# How do I syntax check a Bash script without running it?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, syntax, gnu

Is it possible to check a bash script syntax without executing it?

Using Perl, I can run `perl -c 'script name'`. Is there any equivalent command for bash scripts?

Comment: Related: [Is there a static analysis tool like Lint or Perl::Critic for shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3668665/320399)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

```
bash -n scriptname
```

Perhaps an obvious caveat: this validates syntax but won't check if your bash script tries to execute a command that isn't in your path, like `ech hello` instead of `echo hello`.

Comment: In bash's manpage, under "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS / set", -n is documented, and as the beginning of the manpage states, bash interprets all single-character options that `set` does.

Comment: to add to the (for me) non obvious caveat, it also won't catch an error caused by a missing space `if ["$var" == "string" ]` instead of `if [ "$var" == "string" ]`

Comment: @Brynjar That's because it's just syntax checking. The open bracket isn't syntax, that's the name of the function to run. `type [` says "[ is a shell builtin". It ultimately delegates to the `test` program, but it expects a closing bracket, as well. So it's like `if test"$var"`, which isn't what the author meant, but is syntactically valid (say $var has a value of "a", then we will see "bash: testa: command not found"). Point is that syntactically, there is no missing space.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: Builtin `[` is only invoked in this case if `$var` happens to expand to an _empty string_.
If `$var` expands to a _non-empty_ string, `[` is _concatenated_ with that string and is interpreted as a _command_ name (not _function_ name) by Bash, and, yes, that is _syntactically_ valid, but, as you state, obviously not the intent.
If you use `[[` instead of `[`, even though `[[` is a shell _keyword_ (rather than a builtin), you'll get the same result, because the unintended string concatenation still overrides recognition of the keyword.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: Bash is still _syntax_-checking here: it's checking _simple-command invocation_ syntax: `["$var"` is  _syntactically_ a valid _command-name_ expression; similarly, tokens `==` and `"$string"` are valid command _arguments_. (Generally, builtin `[` is parsed with _command_ syntax, whereas `[[` - as a shell _keyword_ - is parsed differently.)
The shell builtin `[` does _not_ _delegate_ to the "`test` program" (external utility): `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh` all have _builtin_ versions of both `[` and `test`, and they do _not_ call their external-utility counterparts.

Comment: The bottom line is: using just Bash itself, `-n` is your best bet, but that won't catch many errors beginners are likely to make; to catch these, use http://shellcheck.net or its CLI, as detailed in [dvd818's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19573083/45375).

Comment: Another caveat: won't take in account options set in script.  Eg if you add `shopt -s extglob` and then do `foo@(bar|baz))` in `case`, `bash -n` will see that as syntax error (`bash -s extglob -n` will not, but you never know which part of the script is affected)

Comment: @AloisMahdal Unfortunately that would be impossible to fix in the general case, since shell options can change mid-script or even based on information that can only be known at runtime.

Comment: Here's the documentation from `man bash`: `-n Read commands but do not execute them. This may be used to check a shell script for syntax errors. This is ignored by interactive shells.`

Comment: is the -n option version or os specific; doesnt seem to work on osx

Answer (score 160):

Time changes everything. [Here is a web site](http://www.shellcheck.net) which provide online syntax checking for shell script.

I found it is very powerful detecting common errors.

[image]

#### About ShellCheck

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/about.html) is a static analysis and linting tool for sh/bash scripts. It's mainly focused on handling typical beginner and intermediate level syntax errors and pitfalls where the shell just gives a cryptic error message or strange behavior, but it also reports on a few more advanced issues where corner cases can cause delayed failures.

Haskell source code is available on GitHub!

Comment: Great tip; on OSX you can now also install the shellcheck.net CLI, `shellcheck`, via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install shellcheck`.

Comment: Also on debian&friends: `apt-get install shellcheck`

Comment: For Ubuntu trusty this package must be installed from `trusty-backports`.

Comment: As mentioned above, trusty dependency needed, and can install it as below in ubuntu 14.04: sudo apt-get -f install, then: sudo sudo apt-get install shellcheck

Comment: This is really useful, but it does not use Bash’s parser but its own. In most cases this is good enough and it can identify both parsing and other issues, but there is at least one edge case (and probably others I haven’t seen) where it doesn’t parse quite the same way.

Comment: If you want to run your program only if it passes shellcheck: https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/shellproof

Answer (score 42):

I also enable the 'u' option on every bash script I write in order to do some extra checking:

```
set -u
```

This will report the usage of uninitialized variables, like in the following script 'check_init.sh'

```
#!/bin/sh
set -u
message=hello
echo $mesage
```

Running the script :

```
$ check_init.sh
```

Will report the following :

> ./check_init.sh[4]: mesage: Parameter not set.

Very useful to catch typos

Comment: i set these flags always in my bash scripts, if it passes these, it's good to go "set -o errexit"
"set -o nounset"
"set -o pipefail"

Comment: +1 for `set -u` although this does not really answer the question, because you have to run the script to get the error message. Not even `bash -n check_init.sh` shows that warning

Answer (score 26):

```
sh  -n   script-name
```

Run this. If there are any syntax errors in the script, then it returns the same error message.
If there are no errors, then it comes out without giving any message. You can check immediately by using `echo $?`, which will return `0` confirming successful without any mistake.

It worked for me well. I ran on Linux OS, Bash Shell.

Comment: Though not exactly related to bash syntax check - using set -x and set +x for debugging the full script or sections of the script is quite useful

Comment: Thanks for this didn't know didn't know about the -n but what I wanted was @GuruM > sh -x test.sh as that displays the generated output of the script

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that you can do the following  
At command line:
1) bash -x test.sh #this runs the whole script in 'debug mode'  
2) set +x; bash test.sh; set -x #set debug mode on/off before/after script run   
In the script:
a) #!/bin/bash -x  #add 'debug mode' at top of script  
b) set +x; code; set -x   #add 'debug mode' for any section of script

Comment: `sh -n` will probably not check that the script is valid Bash script. It might give false negatives. `sh` is some Bourne shell variant that is usually not Bash. For example in Ubuntu Linux `realpath -e $(command -v sh)` gives /bin/dash

Answer (score 6):

I actually check all bash scripts in current dir for syntax errors WITHOUT running them using `find` tool:

**Example:**

`find . -name '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 -P"$(nproc)"  -I{} bash -n "{}"`

If you want to use it for a single file, just edit the wildcard with the name of the file.

Answer (score 4):

null command [colon] also useful when debugging to see variable's value

```
set -x
for i in {1..10}; do
    let i=i+1
    : i=$i
done
set -
```

Comment: it use parameter expansions

Comment: this works, because `set -x` shows every line before it is executed

Answer (score 3):

For only **validating** syntax:

> [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) [programPath]

For **running** the program only if syntax passes, so debugging both syntax and execution:

> [shellproof](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/shellproof) [programPath]

Answer (score 3):

Bash shell scripts will run a syntax check if you enable syntax checking with

```
set -o noexec
```

if you want to turn off syntax checking

```
set +o noexec
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [BashSupport plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230?pr=idea) for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which checks the syntax.

Comment: But it won't work if your files don't end with `.sh` or other extension associated with Bash scripts, which is the case if you generate the scripts using some templating tool like ERB (then they end with `.erb`). Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79574 if you want it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

If you need in a variable the validity of all the files in a directory (git pre-commit hook, build lint script), you can catch the stderr output of the "sh -n" or "bash -n" commands (see other answers) in a variable, and have a "if/else" based on that

```
bashErrLines=$(find bin/ -type f -name '*.sh' -exec sh -n {} \;  2>&1 > /dev/null)
  if [ "$bashErrLines" != "" ]; then 
   # at least one sh file in the bin dir has a syntax error
   echo $bashErrLines; 
   exit; 
  fi
```

Change "sh" with "bash" depending on your needs