# Is there a static analysis tool like Lint or Perl::Critic for shell scripts?

Tags: shell, static-analysis, checkstyle

Are there any shell (specifically bash or ksh) checkers that test shell scripts for style, best practices, naming conventions, etc?  (Something like Lint for C, or Perl::Critic for Perl.)

I know with ksh you can do syntax checking by running `ksh -n script.ksh` but I was hoping for something more than just sytax checking - something that parses/analyzes the actual code?

I'm probably out of luck, but I guess it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Debian and Ubuntu projects use a script [`checkbashisms`](http://man.he.net/man1/checkbashisms), that looks for particular patterns that might indicate that someone is relying on `/bin/sh` being `bash`.

Beyond that, most shells have a `-n` option to parse and report errors. You could check your script against several different shells to make sure it uses only portable syntax:

```
for shell in zsh ksh bash dash sh
do
  echo "Testing ${shell}"
  ${shell} -n my_script.sh
done
```

**edit to add**: Since writing this answer, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) has been written, as suggested [in a later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691891/69755). This does a much more thorough job of linting shell scripts than the previous suggestions.

Comment: Cool - that script looks promising!  And judging by my lack of finding anything else, and the lack of responses, I'd say that's probably the only thing out there that does this type of thing.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it me or this option is not in the man page of bash nor zsh ?

Comment: Why can't the bash interpreter of the 21st century give a more useful message like "the 'if' on line 23 has no matching 'fi' ..." instead of frustratingly useless nonsense like this?

$ bash -n /tmp/baa.sh 
/tmp/baa.sh: line 56: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ zsh -n /tmp/baa.sh 
/tmp/baa.sh:56: parse error near `\n'

Comment: @BrianCampbell That's fantastic! I plan to fork a repo just for that snippet!

Comment: It's helpful that this script can perform a basic syntax check on scripts for multiple shells, but it really doesn't answer @BrianH's question regarding parsing/analyzing.

Answer (score 46):

[I found shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/): it tests for common errors in quoting and other things you overlook ("because it works").

Comment: It's too bad it depends on Haskell. It's nice, but haskell is a kinda huge dependency.

Comment: @Shurane - the dependency is necessary only for building, not for running the executable.

Comment: It appears that the only dependency is a browser.

Comment: I too wish that running the binary locally didn't require haskell to build, but I'm thankful for the web interface.

Comment: I just found shellcheck too, and it's a really useful and easy tool.

Comment: I found shellcheck too, and it's a really useful and easy tool. By now it's in Debian testing and Ubuntu trusty-backports. If it's not packaged for your OS yet, Haskell probably is, so a simple `apt-get install cabal` or equivalent followed by `cabal install shellcheck` will probably install it. (Otherwise http://www.stackage.org/install is a good guide for quick Haskell setup.)

Comment: Great tip; on OSX you can now also install the shellcheck.net CLI, `shellcheck`, via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install shellcheck`.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote [shlint](https://github.com/duggan/shlint) to wrap checkbashims and the other basic linting options available to shells presented in Brian's answer.

It's installable via rubygems (`gem install shlint`) as sort of a gag, really, but you only need perl (for checkbashims) and a POSIX compliant shell to interpret the shlint command itself. Should work out of the box on OSX and Ubuntu.