# Is there any tool which can check the bash syntax

Tags: bash

Is there any tool (for win would be fine) which can check my bash syntax,
Im learning the scripting in bash so I need any tool which is capable to checj my scripts if there are any type errors.

Thnaks

Comment: There is simular question  over there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668665/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-like-lint-or-perlcritic-for-shell-scripts

Answer (score 7):

See the `-n` argument to `bash`:

> Read commands but do not execute them.  This may be used to check  a 
>   shell  script for syntax errors.  This is ignored by interactive
>   shells.