# How to find unused variables?

Tags: bash, debugging, sh, lint

How to scan a bash script (or a list of scripts), and detect which variables were defined but never read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a static analysis tool like Lint or Perl::Critic for shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668665/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-like-lint-or-perlcritic-for-shell-scripts)

Comment: reworded to fit the rules

Comment: It's still a duplicate

Comment: @Dimid Your question is more specific ("how do I find unused variables?"), but any answer to this would also be an appropriate answer to the question Vorsprung linked. Which basically means that there is no existing tool that does this. You might try writing one yourself (for scripts that don't do any wild variable munging it's pretty easy), and you could post a new question if you got stuck somewhere along that path.