# How to check for bash shell syntax errors in practice?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check whether a set of scripts are syntactically correct. I know there are couple of posts around suggesting to use `bash -n <script_name>` but I run this and I get nothing out e.g.

**good.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"
```

**bad.sh**

```
#!/bin1/bash1

eco "hello"
```

If I do:

```
$ bash -n bad.sh; echo $?
0
$ bash -n good.sh; echo $?
0
```

So how do you discriminate between good and bad exactly?

Comment: As far as bash knows, there may be a command by the name of `eco`, so this isn't really a syntax error.

Comment: OK I see. If you answer and put a bad example I will accept. Thank you.

Comment: possible dup:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171924/how-do-i-check-syntax-in-bash-without-running-the-script

Comment: I know there are others but they are not specific enough probably.

Comment: In fact, that duplicate covers this exact case :)

Comment: dvd818 showed that there is a website you can use: http://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: I know I saw it before but it doesn't show a bad case, so you run it with multiple possible errors and they all come back ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash -n` checks whether Bash can *parse* the code (that is, the *syntax* is correct), not whether the code is "correct." "Correct" can have a lot of meanings, most of which programs will never be able to verify:

- Can be parsed (`bash -n`).
- Finishes without error (`if ./script.sh; then [...]; fi`).
- Prints something which follows a specific format.
- Prints something useful.
- Any of the above *within a specific environment,* for example one which has a shell interpreter that lives in `/bin1/bash1` and a command `eco` which shows you the most ecologically friendly beer bottles available within a 5 parsec radius.

Comment: It's too bad the `-e` option can't be overloaded with `-n` to indicate something like "check if command is available" (and continue to test for syntax errors).