# How to validate bash command in input?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am wondering how I can validate user input, to check if it is a valid bash command - in terms of syntax? I guess it is not possible to create regex for that. Are there any libraries to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Just show actual error(stderr) if command failed, while execution.

Comment: The issue is, that I want to validate on the front end.

Comment: Almost all character sequences can be interpreted as valid bash command

Comment: Valid related to what? It can be valid on one system and invalid on another. Is it valid when it produces an error output?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, valid in terms of a syntax. I will correct it in the question, to make it clearer.

Comment: You can try a combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171924/how-do-i-check-syntax-in-bash-without-running-the-script and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38849/is-there-an-online-bash-script-testing-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There is no practical way to validate a shell command without running it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will leave the question open for couple of hours, and if nothing pops out, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: This is right. A shell command can only be valid according to the shell itself. Another layer cannot tell if it *will* be valid in that shell. The best you can do is to inspire you from most common keywords. Still, it will be a poor approximation of what the shell can and cannot understand.